# How can to code backpropagation (with SDG) in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, backpropagation

Here I am trying to understand neural networks by coding one from scratch (in numpy only). I did the forward pass (using dot products) successfully. But I have no idea how I should proceed to do the backward pass (partial derivatives with respect to each trainable parameter and update using SDG equation). Loss can be the mean square error for example.
Here is my code so far, I added comments below the code describing what is left.

```
'''
I want to design a NN that has :
               input layer I of 4 neurons
               hidden layer H1 of 3 neurons
               hidden layer H2 of 3 neurons
               output layer O of 1 neurons

'''

import numpy as np

inputs = [1, 2, 3, 2.5]


# -------------- Hidden layers ---------------------------
wh1 = [[0.2, 0.8, -0.5, 1],
           [0.5, -0.91, 0.26, -0.5],
           [-0.26, -0.27, 0.17, 0.87]]
bh1 = [2, 3, 0.5]


wh2 = [[0.1, -0.14, 0.5],
            [-0.5, 0.12, -0.33],
            [-0.44, 0.73, -0.13]]
bh2 = [-1, 2, -0.5]

layer1_outputs = np.dot(wh1, np.array(inputs)) + bh1
layer2_outputs = np.dot(wh2, layer1_outputs,) + bh2


# ------------ output layer ------------------------------
who = [0.1, -0.14, 0.5]
bho = [4]
layer_out = np.dot(who, layer2_outputs,) + bho
# --------------------------------------------------------

print(layer_out)

true_outputs = np.sin(inputs)
# compute RMSE
# compute partial derivatives
# update weights
```

architecture of the NN :
[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.adeveloperdiary.com/data-science/deep-learning/neural-network-with-softmax-in-python/) blog. I do not think you should as "How to do something" here. Make an attempt. If you have an error or face some difficulty, then ask a question.

Comment: Standford CS231n has a very good step-by-step example: https://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-case-study/

Answer (score 2):

Backpropagation in Neural Network uses chain rule of derivatives if you wish to implement backpropagation you have to find a way to implement the feature.
Here is my suggestion.

1. Create a class for your neural network, so you can create a separate function for each task.
2. Use a loop to pass through your network from front to back, and use the chain rule to calculate the partial derivatives at each level.
   Adding sample code, from my old work, refer to GitHub repo for full code.

https://github.com/akash-agni/DeepLearning/blob/main/Neural_Network_From_Scratch_using_Numpy.ipynb

```
    def backpropogate(self, X, y):
        delta = list() #Empty list to store derivatives
        delta_w = [0 for _ in range(len(self.layers))] #stores weight updates
        delta_b = [0 for _ in range(len(self.layers))] #stores bias updates
        error_o = (self.layers[-1].z - y.T) #Calculate the the error at output layer.
        for i in reversed(range(len(self.layers) - 1)):
            error_i = np.multiply(self.layers[i+1].weights.T.dot(error_o), self.layers[i].activation_grad()) # mutliply error with weights transpose to get gradients
            delta_w[i+1] = error_o.dot(self.layers[i].a.T)/len(y) # store gradient for weights
            delta_b[i+1] = np.sum(error_o, axis=1, keepdims=True)/len(y) # store gradients for biases
            error_o = error_i # now make assign the previous layers error as current error and repeat the process.
        delta_w[0] = error_o.dot(X) # gradients for last layer
        delta_b[0] = np.sum(error_o, axis=1, keepdims=True)/len(y)
        return (delta_w, delta_b) return gradients.
```